# How to unit-test usage of PLCrashReporter framework

Tags: ios, unit-testing, plcrashreporter

I am using the `PLCrashReporter framework` to detect crashes and send those to our back end. There, I convert the `PLCrashReport` data structure into a `JSON object`. Now I was wondering how I could unit-test these functionality.

Is there a way to create a `PLCrashReport` from crash file or from source?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking about how to test the conversion on the backend, or in the client?

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit unclear. The conversion from crash report to JSON happens on the client. I want to test this conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using the [PLCrashReport](https://www.plcrashreporter.org/documentation/api/v1.2-beta1/interface_p_l_crash_report.html) API to actually parse the protobuf report, this is a bit more tricky than it needs to be, mainly because the API necessary to create arbitrary PLCrashReport instances — the only option is to parse an actual report.

Your best bet would be to generate a crash report (eg, via [-[PLCrashReporter generateLiveReport]](https://plcrashreporter.org/documentation/api/v1.2-rc2/interface_p_l_crash_reporter.html#a218c870c9be7d6a02ac58734b27cabfd)), use it as a static test resource, and write your tests against that known data.

This is a use case we should support better, though, so I've filed a [PLCrashReporter issue](https://opensource.plausible.coop/bugs/browse/PLCR-510) to track the request.